# Medical experimental design with non-comparable control

Tags: experiment-design, random-allocation, medicine, control-group

My population consists of people at high risk of cardiovascular disease who are identified through standard blood tests. These people, when identified, are prescribed some standard medication.

I will randomly select some of these high-risk people and perform an ultrasound scan to determine if they have plaque or not, the control will just get the standard medication with no ultrasound. The people who received the ultrasound will get to know the results, that is whether they have plaque or not and I cannot randomize who gets to know the results and who doesn't (ethics and so on). Knowing whether they have plaque or not is the treatment, that is I am testing whether people will behave differently knowing this additional information, whether they will take their medication more seriously.

I would like to test the effectiveness of the medication on the people who have plaque (and know it) versus the control, since these people are really at risk and are of interest. My issue is that I am comparing a subgroup within the people who got the ultrasound (those who have plaque) versus the control which (presumably) contains both groups (plaque and no plaque), but since no ultrasound was done on the control I do not know the people who have it (if they do). Is there a way to account for this in the analysis so that I am comparing apples to apples?

Comment: For people who received an ultrasound but do not have plaque, is no medication needed/prescribed?

Comment: @mkt They all get medication, regardless of plaque presence.

Comment: What precisely is the hypthesis? "Knowing you have plaques improves drug adherence"? - You could get that from comparing those with plaques and those without plaques in the ultrasound group. "Having the experience of doppler sonography improves drug adherence"? Then you can compare all patients in the ultrasoud group to all patients with no ultrasound.

Comment: @Bernhard Not quite, my hypothesis is "(for people in the high-risk group) knowing you have plaques improves drug adherence" (as opposed to not knowing), so I am only interested in a subgroup of the at high-risk people. That is why comparing with the ultrasound group with no plaque is not quite what I want, and comparing the whole ultrasound group with the control is also not really of interest. The people at high-risk + plaque and their behavior are of interest (this is where the medication has the most effect).

Answer (score 2):

Let's call those with no ultrasound the Group $C$ (as in Control), the group with Ultrasound and plaques the $A_p$ ($p$ as in *positive*) and those with ultrasound and no plaque the $A_n$ ($n$ as in *negative*).

We can compare the drug adherence in $A_p$ and $A_n$ to investigate, whether having plaques has an influence on drug adherence. Maybe those with plaques feel some extra symptoms and thus adhere more or less to their prescription.

If having plaques does not influence drug adherence, then you can go and compare the $A_p$ to the $C$ group without problems.

If having plaques does influence drug adherence, then you will have to change your design to a waiting group design. Those in $A = A_p \cup A_n$ will have an ultrasound and then be observed for drug adherence whilst the $C$ will be observed for drug adherence then then be ultrasounded later. And adherence can probably measured within weeks whilst plaques probably develop over years, so a later ultrasound is still valid to retrospectively divide $C$ into $C_p$ and $C_n$ so that a comparison of $A_p$ to $C_p$ becomes feasible.

**Alternatively:** You might assume that the effect of having an ultrasound at all and the effect of having and ultrasound and knowing there are plaques are somewhat additive effects so that drug adherence in $C$ is drug adherence in $A$ plus some extra and that some extra is the difference in drug adherence in $A_p$ and $A_n$ but you want to accept such assumptions if a simple waiting group design can give a far more reliable experimental answer?

Comment: How do we deal with the immortal time bias in this case? That is what do we do with the people that die or are otherwise removed from the study before they get the ultrasound in the control?

Comment: Do you think, there will be many to die during the study? I am not quite shure on how much of a bias there will be: As groups $A$ and $C$ are assigned randomly, should not equal shares of participants seize to live in both groups? So in some of them you can't measure plaques, in others you cannot measure drug adherence but comparing only complete data should suffice. Or do you believe that a change in drug adherence will influence mortality this quickly? In that case you should consider to primarily measure survival instead of drug adherence.